# Powershell accessing files with select-string - access is denied

Tags: powershell, access-denied

I have an simple `myscript.ps1` to extract URLs from files, taken from [this tutorial](https://techtalk.gfi.com/windows-powershell-extracting-strings-using-regular-expressions/):

```
$input_path = 'd:\myfolder\*'
$output_file = 'd:\extracted_URL_addresses.txt'
$regex = '([a-zA-Z]{3,})://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)*?'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

I run PowerShell as administrator and then type:

```
D:/myscript.ps1
```

But for most of the paths inside `d:\myfolder` I get:

```
select-string : The file D:\myfolder\templates cannot be read: Access to the path 'D:\myfolder\templates' is denied.
```

The folder is copied from FTP server with WinSCP. I tried to go to folder properties and tick off "read only" box than apply but each time I re-enter the properties it's "read only" again (I'm not sure if that's related to the problem).

I work on Windows 10.

Comment: Looks like `D:\myfolder\templates` is a folder not a file Select-String can work with.

Comment: Are you able to browse to see files in D:\myfolder\templates, and if you see files there are you able to open them? This sounds like an ACL issue to me.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes, I am able both to open and browse those folders without any issues.

Comment: I don't know of the contents of your folders if any. Add the `-File` parameter to the gci and/or supply an extension and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment from @LotPings You could get just the files in `D:\myfolder` by using `-File` parameter from `Get-ChildItem`. This way you will not pass in a directory to `Select-String`.

```
$input_path = 'd:\myfolder'
$Files = Get-ChildItem $input_path -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $output_file = 'd:\extracted_URL_addresses.txt'
    $regex = '([a-zA-Z]{3,})://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)*?'
    select-string -Path $file -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- As `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) I wouldn't use it - not even as part of a variable name.
- You don't need two stacked `ForEach-Object` use `$_.Matches.Values` instead
- Using a file extension in the path could eventually avoid the error
- Using the folllowing script on a copy of this webpage works flawlessly but has a lot of dupes, so I'd append a `|Sort-Object -Unique`

---

```
$FilePath = '.\*.html'
$OutputFile = '.\extracted_URL_addresses.txt'
$regex = '([a-zA-Z]{3,})://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)*?'
Get-ChildItem -File $FilePath |
  Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } |Sort -Unique > $OutputFile
```